# Chrome has invalid Post request header

Tags: python, php, google-chrome, http, sockets

First of all, I apologize for my bad English. Also, I would appreciate it if you could explain your answers simply, since I am only 15. My maths and programming skills are not so good yet.

I am currently trying to program an HTTP server from Scratch. I am in the process of implementing PHP, but I need to read many values from the header.

The code works with Edge, OperaGX and even Internet Explorer. But Google Chrome doesn't send the values from the POST form, so I can't read them either.

Because I can't read the values, I can't pass them to PHP. And because of this, the *$_POST* variable doesn't work when the user is using Chrome.

If someone wants to reproduce the whole thing (its currently windows only), here is the py code:
https://pastebin.com/8qmx7G5G.  And to start the Server:

```
def main() -> None:
    server: Server = Server(docs_dir='docs', port=3033)
    server.activate_php(php_dir='C:\\php',
                        php_ini='c:\\php\\php.ini')
    server.start()
```

Anyway, an POST request usually looks like this:

```
POST /index.php?submit=1 HTTP/1.0
Accept: ...
Refferer: ...

username=Fido&password=example
```

But chrome sends only:

```
POST /index.php?submit=1 HTTP/1.0
Accept: ...
Refferer: ...
```

It's not loading the .php file, after submit the form. Its only raising Error *ERR_CONNECTION_RESET*.

**Update:**
When i access my localhost over http://localhost:3033, then it's not working (Only in Chrome, in Edge, IE and Opera its working). But if i access it with http://192.168.178.45:3033 then it's working. Is this perhaps a security feature of Chrome?

Comment: The headers are the same in both cases. `username=Fido&password=example` is the body, not a header.

Comment: You only call `c.recv()` once. You can't assume that this will return everything that the client has sent. You have to call it in a loop until you get the entire POST request. There will usually be a `Content-Length:` header that tells you how many bytes of body to read.

Comment: But when i use my IP to connect to the localhost, i get the POST data too. Only if i use localhost:3033 in Chrome, it's not working. When i call c.recv() twice, the thread is freezing.

Comment: It's unpredictable. TCP is a stream protocol, there are no defined message boundaries, and `recv()` can split up the data any way it wants.